# I want to check if a word or a set of words exists in a String

Tags: java, android, regex, pattern-matching, wordsearch

My requirement is to check if a group of words or a single word is present in a larger string. I tried using String.contains() method but this fails in case the larger string has new line character. Currently I am using a `regex` mentioned below. But this works for only one word. The searched text is a user entered value and can contain more than one word. This is an android application.

```
String regex = ".*.{0}" + searchText + ".{0}.*";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
pattern.matcher(largerString).find();

Sample String
String largerString    ="John writes about this, and John writes about that," +
" and John writes about everything. ";

String searchText = "about this";
```

Comment: probably it is much more clear if you include the sample input and output desired

Comment: Use regex `.*\bhello\b.*`

Comment: What do you want to match with: `.{0}` ?

Comment: I am exactly researching around what you looked for, it seems like we will have to introduce a boolean variable, then loop using matcher.find() to confirm the same.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just replace line breaks with spaces, and on top of that, convert it all to lower case?

```
    String s = "hello";
    String originalString = "Does this contain \n Hello?";
    String formattedString = originalString.toLowerCase().replace("\n", " ");
    System.out.println(formattedString.contains(s));
```

Edit: Thinking about it, I don't really understand how line breaks make a difference...

Edit 2: I was right. Line breaks don't matter.

```
        String s = "hello";
        String originalString = "Does this contain \nHello?";
        String formattedString = originalString.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(formattedString.contains(s));
```

Comment: Did u check this on the android platform? Note: the text can be UTF-8 encoded and can be Chinese, Japanese or Korean.

Comment: I didn't check that. You'll have to manually test it yourself unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

here is code not using regex.

```
String largerString    = "John writes about this, and John writes about that," +" and John writes about everything. ";
String searchText = "about this";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(searchText);
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(largerString);

if(m.find()){
System.out.println(m.group().toString());
}
```

Result:

`about this`

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have gone through that example. But its not what I am looking for. It doesn't help in multi word search